# Does this recursive sequence have a closed-form?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Inspired by [this simple question at HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/utopian-tree), I was wondering if the following sequence has a closed-form:

$$a_0 = 1; \qquad
a_n = \begin{cases}
       a_{n-1} + 1, & \text{if }n\text{ is even} \\[4pt]
       2(a_{n-1}), & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}
     \end{cases}$$

For example, starting at $n=0$, we have:

$1,2,3,6,7,14,\ldots$

Comment: Look at this in binary. It will help you understand it better:
 1, 10, 11, 110, 111, 1110, 1111, 11110, 11111, 111110, 111111

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like those numbers are already tabulated,

https://oeis.org/A075427

$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{2}+2^{n/2} \left(1+\sqrt{2}+(-1)^n \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)\right)-\frac{3}{2}$$

formula by Paul Barry.

Comment: Accepting this because it's more what I had in mind as a solution

Answer (score 7):

$$a_{2n}=2^{n+1}-1,\qquad a_{2n+1}=2a_{2n}=2^{n+2}-2.$$